# Pandas: how get from df some data

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe `df` defined below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': [111, 222, 444],
        'date': ['21-12-2016', '23-12-2016', '26-12-2016'],
        'url': ['vk.com', 'twitter.com', 'twitter.com']})

print(df)

    ID        date          url
0  111  21-12-2016       vk.com
1  222  23-12-2016  twitter.com
2  444  26-12-2016  twitter.com
```

and a list of `dates`

```
dates = ['21-12-2016', '23-12-2016']
```

I want to be able filter `df` with `dates` such that I get

```
    ID        date          url
0  111  21-12-2016       vk.com
1  222  23-12-2016  twitter.com
```

---

So far, I've tried

```
df['date'] == dates
```

But I get a `ValueError`

> ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 3 vs 2

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_clipboard()
dates = ['21-12-2016', '23-12-2016']
print df[df.date.isin(dates)]
```

Output:

```
    ID          url        date
0  111       vk.com  21-12-2016
1  222  twitter.com  23-12-2016
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `query`

```
df.query('date in @dates')

    ID        date          url
0  111  21-12-2016       vk.com
1  222  23-12-2016  twitter.com
```

---

Using `date` as the index and using `loc`

```
df.set_index('date').loc[dates].reset_index()

         date   ID          url
0  21-12-2016  111       vk.com
1  23-12-2016  222  twitter.com
```

---

Using `numpy` broadcasting

```
df[(df.date.values[:, None] == dates).any(1)]

    ID        date          url
0  111  21-12-2016       vk.com
1  222  23-12-2016  twitter.com
```